# Are brackets required at the end for if-else statements?

Tags: php, netbeans

I just upgraded to netbeans 7.4 and they have a code hinting feature, but they recently added a hint rule that really confuses me. **"If-Else Statements Must Use Braces"**, is this a new php standard? I usually don't add brackets unless it is more than one line (example below). I understand that not using brackets can make it a little more confusing, but I think in some cases it looks elegant... Is this a route that all IDE are taking?

```
if($auth==1){
   // Do a bunch of
   // stuff.
}else
   header('Location: /403/index.html');
```

[image]

Comment: As you mentioned, it's just a hint. So, it's not a new standard, just a reminder so you don't make a mistake. Use of braces **must** be used when it's a _bunch of stuff_ like you wrote

Comment: AFAIK unless you are using single line statements or alternate syntax an opening/closing bracket is needed.  (Unless of course you want a parse error somewhere along the line.)

Comment: I would consider it a bad idea to not use brackets in any case. Not doing so violates most PHP coding standards ([like Zend](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html)) and using them makes your code generally more readable.

Comment: I don`t know if it covers the alternative control statements though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a new php standard?

Not really. It totally depends on the user. You can use it in your code if you want -- it's your coding style. However, the Zend Coding standard requires you to use braces for all `if`, `else`, `elseif` constructs:

From their [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html):

> PHP allows statements to be written without braces in some circumstances. This coding standard makes no differentiation- all "if", "elseif" or "else" statements must use braces.

---

> I understand that not using brackets can make it a little more confusing, but I think in some cases it looks elegant

It's a good idea to use braces if your `if` blocks includes multiple conditions. Say, for example:

```
if ($auth) {
   doStuff();
   anotherOne();
}
```

However, if your code only has a single condition, you may write it without braces. For example:

```
if(is_numeric($n)) echo 'Foo';
```

For very short statements, it's not necessary to use braces, but if your code involves multiple conditions or you're writing code that another developer is going to re-use, then it's best to wrap them in braces. That way, there will not be any confusion when you look at the code in future.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a way to prevent developers from making mistakes, when next time they change the code and add another statement.

also it is more of a suggestive feature, than a rule.

By default all IDEs have implemented this feature (Visual Studio, Netbeans, Eclipse being some of the examples) although this is not a rule imposed by the language compilers.